# How to fetch API in Node.js and send to Reactjs ( youtube video included for more detail explain)

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api

thx for stopping by my question.

I'm currently trying to build a simple weather application **using React for the client-side** and **Node.js as a server-side for fetching the weather API**.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/26HnY.png)

But the **main problem** I'm struggling with is **fetching the data to the client side.**
I've tried using Axios and useEffect for fetching the data. But I have no idea how to do furthermore.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/doBpR.png)

**To give you a better understanding of my question, I created a video.**

https://youtu.be/obzvTHEnd70

And the **source code** is here: https://github.com/good-practice00/node-weather-api

If you can help me out, I would much appreciate it! thank you!

Comment: the video and screenshots help but add the React component's code to the question

Comment: Yes, please add a minimal reproducible example of what you've tried, and what happens when you try it: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @RameshReddy Thank you very much sir for your help!!! The problem has been resolved as I followed your advice!!! Thank you for your time and kind reply again!! God bless you!!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple issues:

use `type="button"` to prevent form submission

```
     <form>
        <input
          type="text"
          name="location"
          value={weather.location}
          placeholder="location"
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
        <button
          type="button"
          onClick={() => {
            handleSubmit(weather.location);
          }}
        >
          Search
        </button>
      </form>
```

`fetchWeather` doesn't have to take an argument as you're maintaining the `weather` state, `weather.location` actually

```
const fetchWeather = async () => {
    const res = await fetch(`/weather/${weather.location}`);
    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    setWeatherInfo(data);
  };
```

Not sure why you are calling `fetchWeather` on mount

```
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchWeather();
  }, []);
```

The right place would be this:

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
    fetchWeather();
    // axios.post("/weather"); maybe you don't need this?
  };
```